# How to connect/allow access from localhost:4200 to phpmyadmin hosted by xampp?

Tags: phpmyadmin, cors, angular6

I'd like to access a database hosted via xampp from my angular6 project hosted on localhost:4200. I get following error:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/phpmyadmin/sql.php?server=1&db=eyrietest&table=eyrie-tabelle&pos=0' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I read something about adding a access-header file to htdocs including "Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:4200/"", but as I am hosting my application via note, I wanted to ask if I can somehow change the phpmyadminfiles in xampp to grant access for everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the answer by adding:
"Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*""
to the httpd.conf file of apache.